# Grid Engine Resource Requirement

Tags: gridengine

Does anyone know about setting a requirement to use a particular cluster node.  I have a server with 128G of RAM that I'd like to sit idle until a user specifically requests something like `-l h_vmem=100G`

Is Grid Engine capable of something like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't specifically need to rely on only `h_vmem` then it's possible to use complexes of type `FORCED`. You can create a new complex in `qconf -mc` called something like `bigmem` and make it of type `FORCED`. Then you just edit your exec host with `qconf -me` and add `bigmem=1` to its complexes section. Now only jobs that are submitted with `-l bigmem` will be queued on to that host.

I don't think it's possible to use just `h_vmem` because the of the way the relop is defined any host with sufficient memory to satisfy a job's request is eligible, so low memory jobs would still be queued on high memory hosts.